# Dundas charts to be download(free) & bind with asp.net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello
May i know link from which i download free Dundas charts for Asp.net.
I have searched but i didnt get it.
Thank you.
Asp.net c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, Microsoft has purchased Dundas charts and now they are available as MS Charts. Not sure, if they bought it or create it.
But you can download MS Charts from here - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C

It's free and has all the functionality you require.

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

Comment: i have this one, but for more interactive which charts will be useful?